# How to create an Excel file which contain only the result using Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using an Excel file as a input `df['input.xlsx']` and I calculated some values from it but when I print them in a new Excel file using: `df.to_excel('output.xlsx')` then the result is printing in the "output.xlsx" file but all the columns from the input file are also printing along with result in the "output.xlsx" file. I just want the result to get printed in the 'Output.xlsx' file.

Comment: @Datanovice you can pass it as an argument: `df.to_excel('output.xlsx', columns=[...])`

Comment: even better thanks @JonClements !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you use df.to_excel(path) it will print the path all the data frame also with index.

Here are some code that I usually use before populating it into excel.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('NAME.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df = df[["COLUMN1", "COLUMN2"]] #the columns you want in the excel
df.to_excel(writer, "SHEET_NAME", index=False)
writer.save()
```